# Java Semaphores: Not blocking and releasing correctly

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

For my current program, I'm trying to make a mock Intersection program, with each of the 4 ways into the intersection as Queue, and each thread in the queue is a "car". Every mock clock tick, a car is allowed through, modifying different counting variables as it goes.

My current problem is that my Semaphores controlling clock tick increasing and cars driving through the intersection seem to not be functioning appropriately. Code below.

```
public class Intersection implements Runnable{

static ArrayList<Queue<Thread>> streets = new ArrayList<Queue<Thread>>();
static ArrayList<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
static int clk = 1;
static int numCars = 0;
static boolean empty = true;
static long state = 1;
static int carsRan = 0; 
static int carsMade = 0;
static int carsToRun = 0;

static Random randomGen = new Random();

static Semaphore carCanGo;
static Semaphore clkUp;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    carCanGo = new Semaphore(1);
    clkUp = new Semaphore(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        Queue<Thread> newStreet = new LinkedList<Thread>();
        streets.add(newStreet);
    }

    numCars = 50;

    if(numCars > 100){
        numCars = 100;
    }

    while(carsRan  < numCars && clk < 30){
        if(carsMade < numCars){
            newCarsArrive();
            if(carsToRun == 0){
                clkUp.release();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("clockups");

        for(int i = 0; i < allThreads.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(allThreads.get(i).isAlive());
        }

        try {
            clkUp.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        clk++;
        carCanGo.release();
        System.out.println("clk: " + clk);

        //check for dead processes
        for(int i = 0; i < allThreads.size(); i++){
            if(!(allThreads.get(i).isAlive())){
                try {
                    Thread t = allThreads.get(i);
                    System.out.println("--Thread " + t.getId() + " Done--");
                    allThreads.remove(i);
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("~~Thread " + allThreads.get(i).getId() + " Not Done~~");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("here");

    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    if (empty) { 
        System.out.println("empty means go");
        empty = false; 
        try {
            carCanGo.acquire();
            drive(randomGen.nextInt(100), t);
            clkUp.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }else { 
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        int randomNum = randomGen.nextInt(3);
        int streetNum = randomNum;
        streets.get(streetNum).add(t);
        System.out.println(t.getId() + " | " + streetNum + " | " + randomNum);

        // wait for someone to signal that it is street[i]’s turn to go 
        boolean spin = true;
        while(spin){
            if(t==streets.get(streetNum).peek()){
                spin = false;
            }
        }

        try {
            carCanGo.acquire();
            drive(streetNum, t);
            clkUp.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

*code was removed because it was known that it worked (drive() and newCarsArrive(), can be re-added upon request)*

in the Main, we have acquire() on clkUp, then release() on carCanGo.
in the Run(), we have acquire() on carCanGo, then release() on clkUp.
Why does this not work when one Semaphore is initialized to 1 and the other to 0?

Comment: Nothing is `volatile` and nothing is `synchronized`; what exactly do you expect to happen here? Memory barriers to be to crossed automatically? This code is one **big** race hazard.

Comment: I also notice a busy wait in there and unsynchronized modification of a non-threadsafe collection. This code cannot and will not work; chuck it. Read a tutorial on Java concurrency. Start again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider busy wait was something i was unsure of how to deal with, and since i didn't know the title of it, wasn't sure how to go about fixing it. as for everything else, is there a guide you'd suggest to get a better idea of how to do this?

Comment: I would start with [Orcale's own tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). Busy wait should never, every, happen - there are a thousand and one ways to avoid busy wait. From the simplest `wait`/`notify` to more advanced approaches like the `Semaphore` your are using already.

Comment: Actually concurrency and multithreading is not anything you can mess with if there is stuff that you dont understand well enough. Probably you can start reading the concurrency lessons in  oracle's java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html